# Logical Arguments: Why is this Multiple Argument Invalid?

Tags: logic

In my understanding, an argument is valid when it is the case that if the premises are true, then the conclusion must be true. I have been given the following argument that if $n$ is both a multiple of $3$ and $4$, then $n$ is a multiple of $12$.

> Suppose $n$ is a multiple of $12$. Then $n = 12k$ for some integer $k$. Since $12=3 \times 4$ we have that $n = 3 \times (4k)$ so it is a multiple of $3$, and $n = 4 \times (3k)$, so it is a multiple of $4$.

In words I think of this as

> if $((n = 3 \times 4k)$ and $(n = 4 \times 3k))$ then $(n = 12k)$

but apparently this argument is invalid. What is wrong with this argument showing that if $n$ is both a multiple of $3$ and $4$ then $n$ is a multiple of $12$?

Comment: You started with "Suppose n is a multiple of 12" ... thus, obviously n=12k for some k.

Comment: The issue is that I have been given that there is something specifically wrong with this argument "showing" that if n is both a multiple of 3 and 4 then n is a multiple of 12. I am not sure what is wrong with the argument.

Comment: Your if statement at the end seems to be completely backwards in sequence of what you suppose in the English above it...

Answer (score 3):

> In words I think of this as
>
> if $((n = 3 \cdot 4k)$ and $(n = 4 \cdot 3k))$ then $(n = 12k)$

And

> but apparently this argument is invalid. What is wrong with this argument showing that if $n$ is both a multiple of $3$ and $4$ then $n$ is a multiple of $12$?

Are two different things.

The first is correct because in general $a\cdot b\cdot k$ is a multiple of $a\cdot b$ since $a\cdot b \mid a\cdot b\cdot k$.

The second is incorrect. Take $a=6$, $b=9$, then $n=18$ is a multiple of both $a$ and $b$, but not of $a\cdot b=54$. This is because a and b aren't relative prime in this example (i.e. they have a common divisor greater than $1$ - $3$, in this example.)

Your 'translation' is also different from your first quote: they start with $n=12k$, you end with it. Implication is not commutative!

Answer (score 0):

You have given an argument for "if n is a multiple of 12, then n is both a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 4". So far the argument is absolutely fine in showing this.

However, you wanted an argument to show that "if n is both a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 4, then n is a multiple of 12". It doesn't show that.

(Here we run into a problem. When a statement is clearly true, but an argument supposedly demonstrating the truth isn't valid, some people find it very hard to accept. A source for an endless number of crackpots claiming to have found simple proofs for the hardest mathematical conjectures. A useful method is to apply the argument to a slightly different and obviously false case. In this case:

> In my understanding, an argument is valid when it is the case that if
>   the premises are true, then the conclusion must be true. I have been
>   given the following argument that if n is both a multiple of 6 and 2,
>   then n is a multiple of 12.
>
> Suppose n is a multiple of 12. Then n = 12k for some integer k. Since
>   12 = 6 x 2 we have that n = 6 x (2k) so it is a multiple of 6, and n =
>   2 x (6k), so it is a multiple of 6.

Now clearly if n is a multiple of 2 and 6, then it is *not* necessarily a multiple of 12. 6, 18, 30, 42 are simple counter examples. )

Here is a possible proof:

Suppose n is both a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 4. Dividing n by 12 gives a result x and leaves a remainder y, which is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 or 11. So n = 12 * x + y.

n is equal to 3 * (4x) + y. Since n is a multiple of 3, y must be 0, 3, 6 or 9. 
n is equal to 4 * (3x) + y. Since n is a multiple of 4, y must be 0, 4 or 8.

Together, y must be 0, therefore n = 12 * x, therefore n is a multiple of 12.

(If you try this argument with 3/4 replaced by 6/2, you find that on one hand y must be 0 or 6, on the other hand y must be 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 or 10, which means y can be 0 or 6 - which doesn't give the result that n is a multiple of 12, which is just as well since very often it is indeed *not* a multiple of 12).

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose n is a multiple of 12. Then n = 12k for some integer k. Since 12 = 3 x 4 we have that n = 3 x (4k) so it is a multiple of 3, and n = 4 x (3k), so it is a multiple of 4.

I'll rewrite this reasoning in a schematic fashion.
1.. n=12*k (assumption)
2.. 12=3*4
3.. n=3*4*k (from 1.. and 2..)
4.. n is a multiple of 3 (from 3..)
5.. n is a multiple of 4 (from 4..)
now, we can add this lines:
6.. n is a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 4 (from 3.. and 4..)
7. if n is a multiple of 12, it is a multiple of 3 and 4 (from 1.. and 6..)

This is different from

> T. if n is a multiple of 3 and 4, it is a multiple of 12.

One thing is A=>B and the other is B=>A.
To prove T., you must start by assuming that n is a multuple of 3 and 4, and conclude that it is a multiple of 12.

One way to do it:
1.. n is multiple of 3 and multiple of 4 (assumption)
2.. n=3*j (from 1..)
3.. n=4*k (from 1..)
4.. 3*j=4*k (from 2. and 3.)
5.. 3*j is multiple of 4 (from 4..). Since 3 doesn't have factors in common with 4, j must be divisible by 4.
6.. j=4*l (from 5..)
7.. n=3*4*l (from 2.. and 6..)
8.. n=12*l (from 7..)
9. if n is multiple of 3 and 4, it is multiple of 12  (from 1.. and 8..)

I'll also add that if you try to repeat this chain to prove that "if n is multiple of 6 and 9 it is multiple of 54" (not true), you wouldn't be able to write line 5.., since 6 and 9 do have factors in common.